# Increase text size in android custom keyboard's key

Tags: keyboard

I am making a custom keyboard in android. I created it successfully.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:keyHeight="7%p"
android:keyWidth="33.33%p">

<Row
    android:keyHeight="5%p"
    android:keyWidth="25%p" >
    <Key
        android:codes="-3"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
        android:keyLabel="Done" />
</Row>
<Row
    android:horizontalGap="100px">
    <Key
        android:codes="49"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
        android:keyLabel="1" />
    <Key
        android:codes="50"
        android:keyLabel="2" />
    <Key
        android:codes="51"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
        android:keyLabel="3" />
</Row>
<Row>
    <Key
        android:codes="52"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
        android:keyLabel="4" />
    <Key
        android:codes="53"
        android:keyLabel="5" />
    <Key
        android:codes="54"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
        android:keyLabel="6" />
</Row>
<Row>
    <Key
        android:codes="55"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
        android:keyLabel="7" />
    <Key
        android:codes="56"
        android:keyLabel="8" />
    <Key
        android:codes="57"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
        android:keyLabel="9" />
</Row>
<Row>
    <Key
        android:codes="46"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
        android:keyLabel="." />
    <Key
        android:codes="48"
        android:keyLabel="0" />
    <Key
        android:codes="-5"
        android:isRepeatable="true"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
        android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_delete" />
</Row>
```

I want to change the text size and give a trailing space (space to the right) of key.
How can I do this?

[image]

I want to create keyboard exactly like this image.

Answer (score 0):

For the textsize using - android:keyTextSize works

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.html#attr_android:keyTextSize

Not sure what you mean by space to the right of they key - if you can clarify, maybe I can help.

Comment: Thanks for reply, But there are two properties 1. android:keyTextSize and 2. android:keyLabelSize.

Comment: I have to use both properties keyTextSize and labelTextSize.By mistake i mentioned keyLabelSize in first comment but it is [labelTextSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.html#attr_android:labelTextSize)

Answer (score 0):

use labelTextSize to change the label size. e.g.

```
<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
      .......
    android:labelTextSize="15sp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
    android:horizontalGap="0px"
    android:verticalGap="0px"
for horizontal or vertical gap between keys.

Also for spacing between keys use some less value for android:keyWidth as right now you are using 33.33% that is for three will be something equivalent to 100%.

for changing Text size of your keylabel [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30701479/how-to-change-the-key-label-size-of-a-custom-keyboard-in-android) link will help you.