# How to change the key label size of a custom keyboard in android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I want to change the size of the keyboard label in my custom keyboard. The code I am using is like this,

```
 <Keyboard
     android:keyWidth="%10p"
     android:keyHeight="50px"
     android:horizontalGap="2px"
     android:verticalGap="2px" >
 <Row android:keyWidth="32px" >
     <Key android:keyLabel="A" />
     ...
 </Row>
 ...
```

So the issue is, if we take the code above the letter 'A'(label) is too small in my keyboard.

In [KeyBoard class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.html) I can't find any xml attribute to change the visible size of the key label.

How to change the size of the key label?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Size of the text for character keys. `android:keyTextSize` can help.

Set this in your layout xml file, like this:

```
<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
    android:id="@+id/keyboard_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:keyBackground="@drawable/key_background"
    android:keyTextColor="@android:color/white"
    android:keyTextSize="20sp"/>
```

Comment: I tried both android:keyTextSize="25sp" and android:labelTextSize="25sp" like this. But it doesn't change

Comment: @chathura2020 you should set this parameter in your layout xml. `<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView android:keyTextSize="28sp"/> `

Comment: can you explain where in the xml file should I place this tag?? within which tag eg: <KB><Row>, <Key>

Comment: @chathura2020 No, it is not in this file. It is in your layout file. Just like this  `<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
            android:id="@+id/keyboard_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:keyTextSize="20sp"
            />`

Comment: thanks , it is working. but need to do a small correction. its android:labelTextSize="20sp"

Comment: @chathura2020 `android:keyTextSize="20sp"` works for me.  And `android:labelTextSize="20sp"` does not work. It is so strange.

Comment: I think its because I am using emoji icons. not letters. (I put that code segment just to get a understanding of the xml structure)